# Why would this partial view return a blank?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a partial view that I am creating to apply a special format to some decimal numbers. Here is the partial view ("_Dollar"):

```
@model decimal?
@if (Model.HasValue) 
{ Html.Display(Model.Value.ToString("$#,0.00;$#,0.00-;0.00")); }
else { Html.Display("0.00"); }
```

Here is the calling line of code:

```
<td style="text-align:right;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalBill, "_Dollar")</td>
```

Any ideas of what might be going on?

**Update**: I should add, when running debug, the partial view is called and runs as I would expect it to. To me, is seems the problem is with how I am using `Html.Display`.

**Update**: I understand based on @Gaby's answer why my previous trial doesn't work. I made the changes, but it still doesn't work. On my view I have `@Html.Partial("_Dollar",item.TotalBill)` in the partial view I now have:

```
@model decimal?
@if (Model.HasValue) 
{ Html.Raw(Model.Value.ToString("$#,0.00;$#,0.00-;0.00")); }
else { Html.Raw("0.00"); }
```

Comment: Whts wrong with using `@Html.Partial("_Dollar")` . You can declare the partial in model in there. etc etc

Comment: I forgot about the Partial option, but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.Display` does not do what you think it does.. read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310180%28v=VS.98%29.aspx

You should use

```
@model decimal?
@if (Model.HasValue) 
{ @Html.Raw(Model.Value.ToString("$#,0.00;$#,0.00-;0.00")); }
else { @Html.Raw("0.00"); }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was wondering. I'll have to try that when I get back to work on the 3rd.

Comment: Figured out the problem. I added the `@` before the `Html.Raw` and it worked.